# Lookup "NAME" within range of cells and return "TEXT" few cells above the lookup "NAME" in another Cell

Tags: excel

Using Excel2021

I'm trying to make a formula to solve my problem, if it is possible.
I tried searching many formula online but it didn't fit in the formula I want to use on my file

[SHEET2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1hSZ.png)

[SHEET1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuOst.png)

on SHEET 2 CELL(B12) write formula, IF(B4:H4) and (B7:H7), contains the TEXT "Billy 1" then return the value 2 rows above the answer "Billy 1" that is the Date (Shown the Date 22-Jan-22) into Sheet 1 CELL (B4).

another Cell but same question

on SHEET 2 CELL (B14) write formula, IF(B4:H4) and (B7:H7), contains the TEXT "Billy 2" then return the value 2 rows above the answer "Billy 2" that is the Date (Shown the Date 25-Jan-22) into Sheet 1 CELL (C4).

another Cell but same question different name

on SHEET 2 CELL (F12) write formula, IF(B4:H4) and (B7:H7), contains the TEXT CAPS LOCK "MARY 5" then return the value 5 rows above the answer "MARY 5" that is the Date (Shown the Date 21-Jan-22) into Sheet 1 CELL (F8).

Answer (score 0):

You need the Vstack function in your Excel version.

Replace semicolon with comma, if your Excel version requires.

To make you understand better, i developed the formula in small steps

```
=HSTACK('sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4;'sheet 2'!$B$7:$H$7)

=MATCH(B3;HSTACK('sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4;'sheet 2'!$B$7:$H$7);0)

=IF(MATCH(B3;HSTACK('sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4;'sheet 2'!$B$7:$H$7);0)>=COLUMNS('sheet 2'!$B$2:$H$2);MATCH(B3;HSTACK('sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4;'sheet 2'!$B$7:$H$7);0)-COLUMNS('sheet 2'!$B$2:$H$2);MATCH(B3;HSTACK('sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4;'sheet 2'!$B$7:$H$7);0))

=INDEX('sheet 2'!$B$2:$H$2;IF(MATCH(B3;HSTACK('sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4;'sheet 2'!$B$7:$H$7);0)>=COLUMNS('sheet 2'!$B$2:$H$2);MATCH(B3;HSTACK('sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4;'sheet 2'!$B$7:$H$7);0)-COLUMNS('sheet 2'!$B$2:$H$2);MATCH(B3;HSTACK('sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4;'sheet 2'!$B$7:$H$7);0)))


=IFNA(INDEX('sheet 2'!$B$2:$H$2;IF(MATCH(B3;HSTACK('sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4;'sheet 2'!$B$7:$H$7);0)>=COLUMNS('sheet 2'!$B$2:$H$2);MATCH(B3;HSTACK('sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4;'sheet 2'!$B$7:$H$7);0)-COLUMNS('sheet 2'!$B$2:$H$2);MATCH(B3;HSTACK('sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4;'sheet 2'!$B$7:$H$7);0)));"not found")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Prema, I'll try to redo my task

Answer (score 0):

This formula is much simpler and doesn't requirde Vstack

I made the formula in small steps to make you understand better:

```
=MATCH(B24;'sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4;0)

=MATCH(B24;'sheet 2'!$B$7:$H$7;0)

=IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(B24;'sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4;0)));MATCH(B24;'sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4;0);MATCH(B24;'sheet 2'!$B$7:$H$7;0))

=INDEX('sheet 2'!$B$2:$H$2;'sheet 1'!E35)

=INDEX('sheet 2'!$B$2:$H$2;IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(B24;'sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4;0)));MATCH(B24;'sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4;0);MATCH(B24;'sheet 2'!$B$7:$H$7;0)))

=IFNA(INDEX('sheet 2'!$B$2:$H$2;IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(B24;'sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4;0)));MATCH(B24;'sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4;0);MATCH(B24;'sheet 2'!$B$7:$H$7;0)));"not found")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This was very helpful Prema, As I cannot use other tools (Vstack or Hstack)in Excel to solve for certain reason.

Answer (score 0):

Now I figured out an even more easy formula!

```
=MATCH(1;('sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4=B45)+('sheet 2'!$B$7:$H$7=B45);0)

=INDEX('sheet 2'!$B$2:$H$2;E54)

=INDEX('sheet 2'!$B$2:$H$2;MATCH(1;('sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4=B45)+('sheet 2'!$B$7:$H$7=B45);0))
```

This is the final formula

```
=IFNA(INDEX('sheet 2'!$B$2:$H$2;MATCH(1;('sheet 2'!$B$4:$H$4=B45)+('sheet 2'!$B$7:$H$7=B45);0));"not found")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Prema, Thanks again I’ll try to use the new Formula you provided.

Comment: Will it be possible to ask for another help I need please this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74084039/return-date-above-the-certain-text-from-the-name-in-excel2021 Thanks Prema