# Return Date above the Certain "TEXT" from the "NAME" in (Excel2021)

Tags: excel

Good Day to you,

Is it possible to do the formula without any addons like Vstack or Hstack, just the normal excel 2021.

**QUESTION**
I want to Find the PH 1 taken with different year for certain Name
In Sheet "Public Holiday" If I put the year next to PH 1, Example "PH 1 (2021)". it can return the value but I need match with the 'NAME"
I want to keep the PH 1 Separately from the year

Example:
Name: **Mary CELL(B5)**
Search For: **PH 1 (2021) - CELL (C3)&(C2)**
Within: Sheet **January,February,March**
Return: Sheet **"Public Holiday" into CELL "C5"**

Example 2:
Name: **Billy CELL (B12)**
Search For: **PH 5 (2022) - CELL (G11)&(C10)**
Within: Sheet **January,February,March**
Return: Sheet **"Public Holiday" into CELL "G12"**

**PUBLIC HOLIDAY**
[image: PUBLIC HOLIDAY]
in CELL D4
`=IF(COUNTIF(January!$C$4:$I$12,D3),MIN(IF(January!$C$4:$I$12=D3,January!$C$3:$I$3,"")),"")`
in CELL C12 `=IF(COUNTIF(January!$C$4:$I$12,C11),MIN(IF(January!$C$4:$I$12=C11,January!$C$3:$I$3,"")),"")`

**JANUARY**
[image: JANUARY]
**so Basically I am trying to let's say find in SHEET 'Public Holiday' CELL(C3)&CELL(C2) Matching the name of the person in SHEET 'January to March' return the Value to CELL(C4)**

**FEBRUARY**
[image: FEBRUARY]

**MARCH**
[image: MARCH]

Please help me with this
I hope I made the question right to understand
Thank you very much

Comment: Hmmmm I see what if I put the the whole year schedule in one page.so basically there is only 2 sheets now. Will it be possible to make the formula to lookup “PH 1 (2021)” to “PH 12 (2022) for each individual returning the date on each day they have took. Thanks again Prema..